# SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

I want to use `bodyParser` on express. My `posts.js` file has

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Post = require('../models/Post');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

On `app.js` file, the code is like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const postsRoutes = require('./routes/posts');
// const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/posts', postsRoutes);
// app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
```

Dependencies versions are

```
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.9.7",
"nodemon": "^2.0.3"
```

Server connected successfully but when I pass the data through postman on json mode, the terminal shows error like
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 3
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)...`
I used the following code on `app.js`

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

because now `express` has buiild-in `body-person` function but output same here.

What can I do to solve this problem? I need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are using `express 4.17.1` the body parser is inbult. The second part of the code `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` `app.use(express.json());` should be enough and u can remove the `body-parser` module+code altogether. How are u posting the data via postman, can u update the question with a screenshot?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/rwji9u This is the postman screenshot link

Comment: Have posted the answer based on the screenshot, see if that works.

Comment: Yes, now solved this problem. I forgotten to add " " in title and description attribute on postman. Now works well. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON keys must be strings, try the following in the postman payload:

```
{
    "title": "Title here",
    "Description": "Description here..."
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
    title: "Title here",
    Description: "Description here..."
}
```